# Mockito bundle cannot find org.hamcrest package even though Hamcrest is a dependency

Tags: eclipse, osgi, mockito, tycho, target-platform

I work on an Eclipse 4 RCP project with one plugin bundle and a bundle fragment for unit tests. The target platform is defined with an Eclipse target definition (.target file). Maven with Tycho is used to build the project outside of Eclipse (manifest-first with the .target file defining the target platform).

Now I want to include Mockito in the target platform for mocking. Eclipse Orbit provides an org.mockito (1.9.5) bundle. It depends among other things on org.hamcrest (which can also be found on the Orbit p2 site) so I added it to the target definition as well. When I set Eclipse's target platform from the target file the following shows up in the Target Platform State view:

[image: Target Platform State: both hamcrest and mockito present but mockito claims missing imported package org.hamcrest]

Even though both org.hamcrest.library and org.hamcrest.core are present (both bundles export the org.hamcrest 1.3.0 package) the org.mockito bundle claims to miss the org.hamcrest package.

Nevertheless I added the org.mockito and org.hamcrest.library to the test plugin fragment's dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF.

```
Require-Bundle: org.junit;bundle-version="4.11.0",
 org.hamcrest.library;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.mockito;bundle-version="1.9.5"
```

The fragment seems to compile but the tests cannot be run. The tycho-surefire-plugin reports:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file [...]\target\work\configuration\1405514016520.log.
```

The log file reads:

```
!SESSION 2014-07-16 14:33:34.053 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties F:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Bachelorprojekt\Code\myplugin.tests\target\surefire.properties
Command-line arguments:  -data F:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Bachelorprojekt\Code\myplugin.tests\target\work\data -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties F:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Bachelorprojekt\Code\myplugin.tests\target\surefire.properties

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64/3.102.1.v20130827-2048/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64-3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64/3.102.1.v20130827-2048/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64-3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.508
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.mockito/1.9.5.v201311280930/org.mockito-1.9.5.v201311280930.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.509
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.hamcrest_[1.0.0,2.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Bundle myplugin.tests_0.0.1.qualifier [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 myplugin.tests 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.mockito_1.9.5.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Bundle org.mockito_1.9.5.v201311280930 [5] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package COM.jrockit.reflect_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package jrockit.vm_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.hamcrest_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.configuration_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.base_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.misusing_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.stacktrace_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.547
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.verification_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.invocation_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.listeners_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.mock_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.plugins_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.runners_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.stubbing_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.stubbing.answers_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.verification_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package sun.reflect_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20130827-2048 [147] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.102.1.v20130827-2048 [148] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.548
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64/3.102.1.v20130827-2048/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64-3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64/3.102.1.v20130827-2048/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64-3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../../../../.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.mockito/1.9.5.v201311280930/org.mockito-1.9.5.v201311280930.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.804
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.hamcrest_[1.0.0,2.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Bundle myplugin.tests_0.0.1.qualifier [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 myplugin.tests 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.mockito_1.9.5.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Bundle org.mockito_1.9.5.v201311280930 [5] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package COM.jrockit.reflect_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package jrockit.vm_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.833
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.hamcrest_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.configuration_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.base_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.misusing_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.stacktrace_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.verification_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.exceptions.verification.junit_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.invocation_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.834
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.listeners_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.mock_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.plugins_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.runners_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.stubbing_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.stubbing.answers_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.mockito.verification_[1.9.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.mockito 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package sun.reflect_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20130827-2048 [147] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.102.1.v20130827-2048 [148] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 2 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.835
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-07-16 14:33:40.857
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bundle myplugin.tests is not found
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.getBundleClassLoader(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Launching the plugin test from Eclipse PDE yields effectively the same mockito-related errors (the SWT-related ones are missing but instead there are other bundle resolution errors since I do not usually run these tests from Eclipse and did not eliminate some conflicting bundles from the launch configuration).

What are probable causes for the missing imported-package error even though the package is definitely exported by another required bundle from the target platform and how can I fix this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that org.hamcrest is a split package. There is obviously a bug in tycho or in eclipse, that prevents that from working. See the followings for details:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334540
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=403196

Please give a try to my re-packaged version of Hamcrest and Mockito (Powermock-OSGI). In my version the Mockito manifest specifies, that only the "core" part of the `org.hamcrest` package is needed by Mockito:

Orbit version:

```
Import-Package: COM.jrockit.reflect;resolution:=optional,jrockit.vm;re
 solution:=optional,junit.framework;resolution:=optional,org.apache.to
 ols.ant;resolution:=optional,org.apache.tools.ant.types;resolution:=o
 ptional,org.hamcrest;version="[1.0,2.0)"
```

My version:

```
Import-Package: org.hamcrest;core=split,junit.framework,org.junit,org.ju
 nit.internal.runners,org.junit.runner,org.junit.runner.manipulation,org
 .junit.runner.notification,org.junit.runners,org.junit.runners.model,or
 g.objenesis;version="[2.1,3)"
```

The update site can be found at http://powermock-osgi.googlecode.com/svn/updateSite/1.5.4.1/

Project home: https://code.google.com/p/powermock-osgi/

Before taking my update site, you might need to delete Eclipse and Tycho bundle pools as written at Powermock-OSGI site:
First Time Usage

> Tycho and Eclipse PDE caches the bundles based on symbolic name and
>   version. So if the user already had a 4.11 version of Junit anytime in
>   the past, our hacked powermock version will not be taken.
>
> So before first usage inside Eclipse the user has to delete the
>   .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool and
>   .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.external_libraries in ALL
>   workspaces of the specific Eclipse installation (bundles are looked up
>   cross workspace way). BE SURE, that when you run the unit tests in
>   eclipse the plugins tab in the launch config REALLY contains the
>   JUnit, Mockito and Hamcrest plugins of the Powermock feature, and not
>   some other version. Before first usage with Tycho delete the .meta
>   .cache and p2 folders from the maven local repository

Please send me a feedback if it works.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as CramB did, after including the mockito-junit feature org.objenesis [2.1.0,3.0.0) is reported missing as it is not part of the feature. We do not use a local p2 site for target platform provisioning so I cannot simply copy the bundle from the powermock site. Could you provide a feature including the objenesis bundle, please? Orbit has only objenesis 1.0.0 availabe.

Comment: http://powermock-osgi.googlecode.com/svn/updateSite/1.5.4.1/plugins/ is a simple remote update site, which you can add to your target file. If you add the URL and you choose the feature it is possible then to filter the added bundles on the "content" tab of the target file editor. There is a 2.1.0 objenesis on my site.

Comment: Eclipse's target definition editor tab only allows the selection of features when editing the provisioning locations (or I have always missed a helpful switch...). Hence I could not add the single bundle to the platform as it is not included by a feature. I edited the target file by hand to add the bundle and it works fine now. Thank you! Note that you have to leave out the trailing /plugins in the URL above for the target editor, in the answer it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently having the same problem, in both Tycho build and starting a runtime Eclipse from PDE:

```
!ENTRY org.mockito 4 0 2018-03-14 11:53:00.671
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.mockito [6]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: COM.jrockit.reflect; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: jrockit.vm; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant.types; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.hamcrest; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
```

I was able to solve this in both cases without needing a re-packaged Mockito.

- In PDE by adding the `org.hamcrest` explicity to the target platform instead of just `org.hamcrest.core`:

[image]

corresponding `.target` code:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.hamcrest" version="1.1.0.v20090501071000"/>
<unit id="org.mockito" version="1.9.5.v201605172210"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180206163158/repository/"/>
</location>
```

- And in Tycho by doing the equivalent:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <configuration>
          <dependency-resolution>
              <extraRequirements>
                  <!--  Workaround for an issue with mockito depending on hamcrest -->
                  <requirement>
                      <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                      <id>org.hamcrest</id>
                      <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                  </requirement>
              </extraRequirements>
          </dependency-resolution>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that Tycho could not resolve Hamcrest correctly. In my project I used my build my own target platform (just a few plugins from Luna SDK). For unit tests I took the JUnit bundle from the SDK. When I added the Mockito library I faced the same problem described above. At first I also experimented with repackaging the Mockito bundle with concrete versions. But I couldn't fix it. Then I found your question and Gábor's answer, which finally solved my problem!

At first I followed the instruction and added the update site and chose the needed feature (Powermock with Mockito and JUnit). Then I ran into unresolved dependency with Objenisis bundle. I don't know if this is my specific problem because I made my own target platform with a few bundles or that Objenisis is just missing in the feature?!

So I copied the needed bundles (incl. Objenisis) from the powermock-osgi update site to my own target platform and now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem and couldn't figure out a way by using the orbit [`R20200224183213`](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200224183213/) bundles.

Finally I just downloaded [`mockito-all`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19), placed it into the libs folder and added it to my test plug-in's runtime classpath (`MANIFEST.MF -> Bundle-ClassPath`).

[image: Mockito as library classpath]

I hope they will fix it in the next orbit versions so that I can use the orbit bundles again.